# Swift 3 error: [_SwiftValue pointSize] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsstring, uifont

I just migrated our project to swift 3 and see lots of crashes because of one issue:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance*

The reason for that error is the call to:

```
[NSAttributedString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:context:]
```

What I noticed is that if I cast String to NSString and call `boundingRectWithSize` on it it will throw that error. It also seems to be happening in many other parts, for example if I sent a view controller title in a storyboard it throws the same error.

Anyone having the same problems?

**To reproduce the problem:**

Create a new Swift 3 project in Xcode 8 and add the following line in viewDidLoad:

```
let attributes: [String: AnyObject?] = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        ]
    let boundingRect = ("hello" as NSString).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
```

But as I said it crashes in many other places as it seems that UIKit uses this method internally in many parts

Comment: Please show your code causing the issue with relevant parts.

Comment: Looks like it's related to the internal implementation of NSString

Comment: I'm getting the same crash but for this: (textLabel.text! as NSString).size(attributes: fontAttributes)

I've tried everything from using nsmutablestring, appending strings to it etc. it still crashes. This is apples fault no doubt. Really really bad. Cannot migrate.

Comment: Similar crash. What is Apple doing! (No I'm not force unwrapping "doing" ;) )

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If I use your test code, but let the data type of `attributes` default, it doesn't crash.  That is:

```
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]
```

Option-clicking on the variable says it's `[String : UIFont]`.

A little extra testing, suggests that it's related to the optional object; `[String: AnyObject]` appears to work OK.

EDIT:
And after all that, I decided to read the documentation, which says to use `[String: Any]`.  :)

Comment: good catch, Phillip. One point here, if someone is using custom font then the font should be unwrapped: `UIFont(name: UIFont.lightFontName(), size: 14)!`

Comment: Right, because `UIFont(name: size:)` returns a `UIFont?`.  You would need to unwrap it before creating the dictionary entry...but preferably not with `!` (unless crashes are a requirement).

Comment: Had a very similar problem but with color. `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` was being set with an optional NSColor (yes NS-, on macOS). pre 3.0 that would error. Not very happy with some of the new optional handling.

Comment: I had the same error in someLabel.sizeToFit(). As we can see in my and Leonid's case we wanted to get the rect of the string. So we can assume that Apple wants us to always use unwrapped fonts to make their calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The following fixed it for me:

```
let attributes: [String: UIFont] = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func attributedString(firstText : String, amount : String, fontSize : CGFloat, color : UIColor) -> NSAttributedString {

    let attrDict = [ NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: fontRegular, size: CGFloat(fontSize/2))!,
                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.darkGray] as [String : AnyObject]
    let iconString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: firstText, attributes: attrDict)

    let attrDict1 = [ NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: fontRegular, size: CGFloat(fontSize))!,
                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color] as [String : AnyObject]
    let amountString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: amount, attributes: attrDict1)

    iconString.append(amountString)
    return iconString
}
```

And call it like

lblBalanceAmount.attributedText = self.attributedString(firstText: "My Balance", amount: "500", fontSize: newFontSize, color : UIColor(red: 41/255.0, green: 192/255.0, blue: 42/255.0, alpha: 1.0))

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set the font in the wrong way. I am trying to understand why it fails but here is the solution if you don't want to use a specific font size.

```
let font: UIFont = .body

let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: font.pointSize)
]
```

The ***pointSize*** will give the size of the font type.