# iOS App crashes after migrating to swift3 during navigation

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift3, xcode8

I have migrated my project to Swift3 and after conversion the app crashes whenever I click on any button which loads a new screen. The crash happens in the assembly code so am not able to figure out what's the issue. Control leaves the existing class then goes to assembly language and then crash just before loading the new screen.

This is the error message am getting

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x61000005fb00'

Crash is not happening in any specific code so its difficult identify the error. Please help me to figure this out.

Comment: there is a change in Swift3 syntax for selector and segue. Please check that you are using the correct syntax.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39511309/413337 ?

Comment: @Sharpkits  if this was a syntax error then it would crash in the code where segue is performed but here it crashes in the assembly code

Comment: @Codo that link didn't help. I haven't written any code related to fonts . Also I changed the code in the storyboard to a system font to check whether its an issue with font. That also didn't work

Comment: I created a new viewController and added a segue and that worked..but i can't create a new UI for all the screens in my project :( ..that will definitely take more time..

Comment: Have you tried reconnecting segues? Or reapplying the connections to outlets / actions?

Comment: @mangerlahn - Yup I tried reconnecting segue and still its crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe have a outlet from your storyboard (label, textfield, uiButton...) that is not map anymore in your controller. You should check each component to see if you didn't delete the reference in the controller and no in the storyboard...